# Selectors with Injection

Tags: ngxs

Is possible to inject some service within a selector in NGXS? Since its static I'm not sure how. I know probably it should be avoided but in certain cases injecting a service such as logger or config can be useful and I'm not sure if this can be done.

Checked several docs but didn't find any yet. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You are right. It is possible to inject services into the state class, but since the selectors are static, they will not have access to these services.To pass additional parameters to the selector, try considering [lazy selectors](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select#lazy-selectors).

Comment: That would also work, however I would like not to expose it so the consumer doesnt have to pass it